# calculate aggregate of numpy array with pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe with 2 columns, one is group and second one is vector embeddings. The data is already like that so I don't want to argue about the embedding columns. The embedding columns all share the same number of dimension.

Basically I want to calculate the average of embedding for each group. By average I mean is axis level average. So [1,2] and [4,8] got average to [2.5,5]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"group":["a","a","b","b"],"embedding":[[0,1],[1,0],[0,0],[1,1]]})
df['embedding'] = df['embedding'].apply(np.array)

df.groupby("group").agg({"embedding":"mean"}) #This raise error
```

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in mean(self, numeric_only)
   1497             "mean",
   1498             alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
-> 1499             numeric_only=numeric_only,
   1500         )
   1501 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1079 
   1080         if not output:
-> 1081             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
   1082 
   1083         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, index=self.grouper.result_index)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Expected Output :

```
pd.DataFrame({"group":["a","b"],"embedding":[[0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5]]})
```

Fast solution is very appreciated since my data is quite huge.

Comment: So the elements of that column are 2 element lists, and lists don't do math. `[1,2]+[3,4]` is not `[4,6]`

Comment: thats why i convert it to np.array using `df['embedding'].apply(np.array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `apply` `np.mean`

```
df.groupby('group')['embedding'].apply(np.mean).reset_index()
  group   embedding
0     a  [0.5, 0.5]
1     b  [0.5, 0.5]
```

Comment: This one speed is on par with @Psidom answer but the code is simpler. Love it

Answer (score 2):

If elements in the `embedding` column are guaranteed to be *the same shape numpy arrays*, you can use `groupby` + `apply` and use `Series.mean` method to calculate the elementwise average:

```
df.groupby('group').embedding.apply(lambda g: g.mean()).reset_index()
#  group   embedding
#0     a  [0.5, 0.5]
#1     b  [0.5, 0.5]
```

Comment: Your solution is currently the fastest one and easier to read :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
df = df.groupby("group")["embedding"].apply(lambda x: np.mean(
    np.hstack(x).reshape(-1, 2), axis = 0)).reset_index()
```

Complete Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], "embedding": [
                  [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]]})

df = df.groupby("group")["embedding"].apply(lambda x: np.mean(
    np.hstack(x).reshape(-1, 2), axis = 0)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'embedding':lambda x: x.map(np.array).mean().tolist()})
```